# Setting up a global PhantomJS error handler

Tags: javascript, error-handling, phantomjs

The following code is taking from phantomjs cookbook. I suppose to recieve the following message "`[PHANTOMJS ERROR] Error: Gremlins fed after midnight.`" 
but it doesn't work; it exits without logging anything:

Here is the code:

```
phantom.onError = function(message, trace) {
  console.error('[PHANTOMJS ERROR] ' + message);
  trace.forEach(function(t) {
    console.error(' >> [' + t.line + '] ' +
      (t.function ? '[' + t.function + '] ' : '') +
      t.file || t.sourceURL);
  });
  phantom.exit(1);
};

function doSomeErrorProneStuff() {
  throw new Error('Gremlins fed after midnight.');
}

doSomeErrorProneStuff();
console.log('Exiting cleanly.');
phantom.exit(0);
```

is there something that has been deprecated?

Comment: It's a known bug in PhantomJS 2.0.0. I'm looking for the duplicate now.